# unicorn deployment failure - can't sync when deployed to real environments

Tags: azure, paas, unicorn, deployment

I am sure I am missing something simple about using `Unicorn` in environments above the local dev environments

the source folder is correct out of `Azure Paas`, out on my App Service

I am in `Sitecore 9.3.0`

and `Unicorn 4.1.1`

The source folder is set to the real folder the src was deployed to...

```
<sc.variable name="sourceFolder" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Serialization\src" patch:source="Foundation.Serialization.config"/>
```

But the unicorn control panel claims I need to do an initial serialization, that it cannot sync

> Warning: at least one configuration has not serialized any items yet.
> Unicorn cannot operate properly until this is complete. Please review
> the configuration below and then perform initial serialization if it
> is accurate.

Is there some other setting, some other config I need to make to tell Unicorn is should use the serialized yml files from the sourceFolder location or...

Not sure what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Unicorn gets its location from `<targetDataStore>`, not sure where your `<sc.variable>` comes from. See here: https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/blob/master/src/Unicorn/Standard%20Config%20Files/Unicorn.CustomSerializationFolder.config.example

Comment: Generally I leave Unicorn completely default when on upstream/paas environments, and just mirror the .yml files to App_Data/Unicorn.

Comment: So your advice Mark, if I am reading it right, is to not set the targetdatastore on systems above local-dev?

Comment: Well. I generally don't, since there is no data capture upstream and the YML files therefore do not need to reside in a source controlled folder. But it is not a must. But setting a variable like you do above, that would need something extra for Unicorn to pick up - OOTB configs would not react to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that issue is that you pointing to wrong location. Here are steps, how to make sure that Unicorn points to right location on disk:

1. Open unicorn.aspx
2. Open any Unicorn configuration, scroll to Target Data Store.
3. Find physical root path, copy or remember it
4. Open Kudu SCM, https://your-site-name.scm.azurewebsites.net
5. Open CMD or Powershell in Kudu
6. Navigate D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Serialization\src and navigate to path from step 3.
7. Check that serialization is present in that folder